# Linq Sorted Groupby and Orderby fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I feel I am just on the edge of my answer!

I have a custom `fileInfo` class with holders info such as "reporting store number" , "report date" etc...

I have a `List<fileInfo>` which I hold all file information.  I have attempted to group the list by "reporting store number" and order by "report date"

I have come up with the following

```
var results = ownedFileInfo.GroupBy(x => x.reportStore).Select(group=> new { KeyName = group.Key, KeyInfo =  group.OrderBy(x=>x.reportDate).ThenBy(x=>x.reportStore)});

List<fileInfo> sortedFiles = new List<fileInfo>();
                    foreach (var group in results)
                    {

                        foreach (fileInfo fi in group.KeyInfo)
                        {
                            sortedFiles.Add(fi);

                        }
                    }
```

The groupby and orderby functionality are working as expected.  Although I was hoping the ThenBy would sort the groupby column as well :(

Results:

- Store#.....Date
- 991........10/16/13
- 991........10/17/13
- 994........10/16/13
- 994........10/17/13
- 992........10/16/13
- 992........10/17/13

Expected results:

- Store#.....Date
- 991........10/16/13
- 991........10/17/13
- 992........10/16/13
- 992........10/17/13
- 994........10/16/13
- 994........10/17/13

Could one of the more experience with linq please point out what I am missing or whats going wrong? Thank you in advanced for your time.

Comment: both of your examples show lack of sorting by date, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not good qith linq but I think you are not ordering the `KeyName = group.Key`

Comment: Try ordering the final result with  `results.OrderBy(grp => grp.KeyName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think for that output you need grouping at all:

```
var sortedFiles = ownedFileInfo.OrderBy(x => x.reportStore)
                               .ThenBy(x => x.reportDate)
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is

```
ownedFileInfo.GroupBy(x => x.reportStore).OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Select....
```

instead of

```
ownedFileInfo.GroupBy(x => x.reportStore).Select....
```

Comment: This solution looks like it could be viable too so I gave you an upvote! Thanks good sir